# How to check affected rows before an sql query running?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table with some rows.
by php, I  make a SQL query such as "DELETE * From my_table".
How can I recognize affected rows before running the sql query. On the other words, I want to have the list of affected rows after an sql query and before of its running.

All in all, I want to check somethings before running SQL irreversible queries.

best respects.

Comment: this scenario is impossible

Comment: Btw, *"`DELETE * From my_table`"* - It doesn't work that way, just so you know ahead of time ;)

Comment: As far as I know, it can only be done with two queries. One SELECT and one DELETE, both with the same criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a DELETE query like:

`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE foo='bar'`

To see how many records will be deleted you could first run:

`SELECT count(*) from my_table where foo='bar'`

The result of that query will be the count of records that meet the same condition.

Comment: he said he wants a list of the rows, not just a count.

Comment: Thanks, although I want a list of affected rows, I solved the issue by your idea with some small changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a `SELECT` query with the same `JOIN` and `WHERE` criteria as the `DELETE` would use. This will return the rows that would have been deleted.

If you want perfect safety, you need to use transactions in all the applications that access the tables. The process that's doing the `DELETE` should perform the `SELECT` in the same transaction. Otherwise, another process could add rows to the table between the `SELECT` and `DELETE`, and they might be deleted if they meet the criteria.

If you're just trying to verify the logic of your `DELETE` query with an eyeball examination of the results, this may be overkill.

Comment: This is the simple answer, however if one has concerns over consistency, one would actually need to lock the table to prevent other changes to it between the SELECT and DELETE.

Answer (score 2):

Add the MySQL `EXPLAIN` keyword before your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SELECT and then mysqli_affected_rows to get the number of rows about to get deleted. 
If you want data from the rows as well then you fetch it with SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Create a function that analyzes the rows:**

```
function checkRows($table){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;

    // execute SELECT query
    // get the result
    // using for loop, set $delete boolean based on whether to delete or not

    return $delete;
}
```

**2) Create a function that deletes the stuff:**

```
function deleteFromTable($table){
    $query = 'DELETE FROM ' . $table;

    // execute DELETE query
}
```

**3) Create conditional calls:**

```
$table = 'SomeTable';
$validDelete = checkRows($table);

if($validDelete){
    deleteFromTable($table);
}
```

This will allow you to perform validation of records prior to deletion.

Comment: This won't work if there's a `JOIN` in the `DELETE` query, but you only want to delete from one of the tables in the join.

Comment: @Barmar - true, although the scope of that isnt in the question. it wouldnt be too hard to implement, though, as you would modify your `SELECT` statement to allow for `JOIN`s, then using a `for` loop run the `DELETE` statement with a `WHERE` condition passed to account for the said `JOIN` criteria.